# Why does simple C++ vector function produce subscript out of bounds?

Tags: c++, vector

This is a simple function that takes a vector of integers, and sums up the odd entries only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int f(vector<int> & n)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itA;

    int sum = 0;
    for (itA = n.begin(); itA != n.end(); itA++)
    {
        if (*itA % 2 == 1) sum += *itA;
    }


    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    a[0] = 3;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 6;
    a[3] = 1;
    cout << f(a) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

When run, it crashes due to a vector subscript out of range. Why is this the case? The iterator begins at vector.begin(), and goes through the vector while the iterator does not point to vector.end(), which should be the entire vector.

Comment: You have not defined the size of vector before using it or else use push_back function of vector container

Comment: `vector<int> a = {3, 5, 6, 1};` would be somewhat simpler, not to mention; would actually work ;)

Answer (score 2):

`vector<int> a;` creates an empty vector, and since it is empty (i.e. has no elements), accessing the elements with `a[index]` is always out-of-bounds access, which leads to undefined behavior, and, in your case, a crash. Use `push_back` or `emplace_back` to append elements to the vector.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int f(vector<int> & n)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itA;

    int sum = 0;
    for (itA = n.begin(); itA != n.end(); itA++)
    {
        if (*itA % 2 == 1) sum += *itA;
    }


    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a(4);
    a[0] = 3;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 6;
    a[3] = 1;
    cout << f(a) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```